# XML/XPath: Distinguish equal nodes via siblings

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML of the following form:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C/> <!-- Want to find ONLY this C -->
  </B>
  <B>
    <D/>
    <C/>
  </B>
</A>
```

Is there a way of only finding the element **C** which has no preceding-sibling?
I was looking into *XPath* and *XPathAxes*, but did not come up with a solution...
Does anyone know if there is a way with Xpath-syntax to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is basically what you say: `//C[not(preceding-sibling::*)]`.

Comment: "//C[not(preceding-sibling::*)]" = "every C element which does not have any preceding-sibling elements". An equivalent expression is: "//*[1]/self::C", which means "every element that's the first child of its parent, and which is also a C element"